# size of byte array before and after writing to file is different why

Tags: android, performance

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    Uri imageFileUri = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, bmpFactoryOptions);

    Log.d("SIZE", "mBitmap size :" + data.length);

    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, bmpFactoryOptions);
    imageFileUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
    OutputStream imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageFileUri);
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, imageFileOS);

    imageFileOS.flush();
    imageFileOS.close();


    ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream1);
    byte[] imageInByte1 = stream1.toByteArray();
    long lengthbmp1 = imageInByte1.length;
    Log.d("SIZE", "ByteArrayOutputStream1 size :" + lengthbmp1);
```

**output of the Log is like below :**

> D/SIZE    (23100): mBitmap size :4858755
>   D/SIZE    (23100): ByteArrayOutputStream1 size :8931843

Can anybody help me why this difference.
I need to compress the image based on the size, but without compressing the size getting different..

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be loading the image and then recompressing to bitmap

```
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream1);
```

Then you're wondering why the image size isn't the same? The answer is you've re-encoded it. Is 100 the compression ratio? If you load a bitmap compressed at 80% and then resave it to 100% in any image editor the size will grow.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is why you reencode the bitmap when you already have the bytes. The size difference you observe comes from the different compression. The camera app will typically compress the image with a quality lower than 100 but you recompress it with 100. It is clear that your image representation will need more space.

If recompression is really necessary (for example if you altered the image in some way), try lower quality factors for better compression. Depending on your image something between 90 and 100 may work well.

Comment: I am just trying to know the size of image data, captured from camera. and later I am writing it to a outputsteam file and printing it again the size. but difference is huge. do u know why